# Duplicate contract name

Tags: solidity, warnings

I have two contracts. Contract A is given by:

//A.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
contract A {
   address owner;
   constructor() public{  
      owner = msg.sender;
   }
   function transferTo(address to, uint amount) public {  
      (bool success,) = to.call.value(amount)("");
      require(success);
   }
   function() external payable  {}
}
```

Contract B is given by:

//B.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
interface A {  
   function transferTo(address to, uint amount) external;
}

contract B {
   address owner;
   constructor () public {  owner = msg.sender;}
   function getOwner() public view returns (address) {  return owner;}
   function() external payable  { 
      A(msg.sender).transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance);
   }
}
```

> When I compile the code on Truffle console, I am getting the following
> warning: Duplicate contract names found for A. Somebody please guide
> me how to remove this warning.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the interface from A to something else.